# Why do I Get [[: not found When Running a Script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a script that has to check if a file exists. In the console I write

```
if [[ -a /path/to/file.txt ]]; then echo "not mod"; else echo "mod"; fi
```

and I get

```
not mod
```

but when I write a script to do the same thing:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ -a /path/to/file.txt ]]; then echo "not mod"; else echo "mod"; fi
```

and then execute the script, I get this:

```
./ex.sh: 2: [[: not found
mod
```

I saved the script on the current directory and named it ex.sh, then I made sure it is executable. To call the script I do this:

```
./ex.sh
```

Why am I getting this problem? I already tried many things:

```
if [ -a /home ...
```

and

```
if test -a /home ...
```

Both of them return

```
13: -a: unexpected operator
```

Comment: I was able to make it work, but for that I had to remove the first line (#!/bin/sh) Do you know why this happens?

Comment: try `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: hello kev, I relized that too. I just updated my question. I spent too much time on this, but I'm glad I could solve it. Thanks for your answer. It is indeed, the solution to the problem.

Comment: @Kev Please post that as an answer

Comment: Buzu, @Kev - if you find an answer, *post it as an answer below*, do not edit the question.

Comment: @kev: I edited the question to remove the answer, since all the information is already in the answer you posted.

Answer (score 16):

You are running a script written for *bash* under *sh*, which lacks many of the extended syntax features – `[[` is a `bash` builtin command and is not available in `sh`.

Change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` or to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: On some systems, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`.  And it's probably reasonably safe to assume that `bash` is `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @Keith: It's `/bin/bash` on most Linux systems, but `/usr/pkg/bin/bash` on BSDs, or `/usr/local/bin/bash` if one compiles directly from source.

Comment: @grawity: Or wherever else you decide to put it if you compile from source.  Ok, good point.  Personally, I'd rather edit the shebang for each system than use the `/usr/bin/env` hack (which uses whichever `bash` happens to be in the callers `$PATH` at the moment), but YMMV.  (And you can make `/bin/bash` a symlink -- if you have admin rights and you don't mind messing with `/bin`.)

Comment: @Keith: `/usr/local` is where autotools decides to put it by default. As far as "personally" goes, I like having several different servers and VMs pull from the same scripts/tools repository, and not needing to re-edit the shebangs on half of them after every commit.

Comment: none of them worked for me :/ im on centos

Answer (score 0):

Specify bash instead of sh when running the script. I personally noticed they are different under ubuntu 12.10:

`bash script.sh arg0 ... argn`